# Running fop as www-data on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apache-fop

I'm trying to run FOP (via php exec() command) and when I run FOP on the command line (as my user) it works perfectly fine, however the PHP command is running it as the www-data user for apache and it is saying FOP not found.

If i run it on the command line with sudo -uwww-data fop then it also says command not found.

I've put my fop path info into /etc/environment along with /etc/profile and I've done a source /etc/environment and a source /etc/profile but it still says it's not found.

How do I get FOP to run under the www-data user?

Thanks

Comment: Just to get this rolling: If the java classpath were the problem, you would get something like a `ClassDefNotFoundException` and a stack trace on STDERR. What version of Ubuntu are you running? Does `which fop` and `sudo -uwww-data which fop` return `/usr/bin/fop`? Does calling other programs in `/usr/bin` result in a similar error? Are you the admin of the system, or did some over-zealous admin impose weird "security" restrictions?

Comment: Hi, not the javaclass path, just the CLASSPATH environment variable, like so:


PATH="opt/fop/latest:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"

doing which fop doesn't work either.

I'm the admin of the box and it's just standard out of the box security as far as I know.

Ubuntu version is 12.04 b64bit

Comment: Also, I've just sudo'ed in as the www-data user (sudo -s -uwww-data) and gone to the /opt/fop/latest directory and ran fop and it worked that way, it's just like the www-data user doesn't know how to read my CLASSPATH

also doing

sudo -uwww-data /opt/fop/latest/fop -version

works

so if I give it the absolute path it works, but obviously I don't want to have to specify the install path as this should be specified in my PATH environment variable

Comment: I keep saying CLASSPATH but I mean PATH :p

Comment: What does this command output? `echo 'whoami; echo PATH=$PATH' | sudo -u www-data sh` Does it differ from the path you gave above?

Comment: Yeah it's different, has no mention of fop in there.

Answer (score 0):

Putting following code into a file named like `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` is a horrible way to achieve your goal, but it might even work:

```
#/bin/sh
if [ "`id -u`" -eq "`id -u www-data`" ]; then
   PATH="/opt/fop/latest:$PATH" ;
fi
```

We test if the current user id is the id of the `www-data`-user. If so, we prepend the `PATH` variable with the `/opt/fop/latest` directory. It should be automatically run whenever a new shell is being initialized.

These commands will install the new script:

```
$ echo -e '#!/bin/sh\nif [ "`id -u`" -eq "`id -u www-data`" ]; then PATH="/opt/fpb/latest:$PATH"; fi' | sudo cat >/etc/profile.d/fop4www-data.sh
$ sudo chown www-data:www-data /etc/profile.d/fop4www-data.sh
$ sudo -u www-data chmod +x /etc/profile.d/fop4www-data.sh
```

If the command

```
$ echo 'whoami; echo PATH=$PATH' | sudo -u www-data sh
```

run from a normal shell reflects the change, you should be able to call `fop` from your php script.

*DISCLAIMER*: I'm not that into shell programming. I have near to no idea what I'm doing. Please use common sense and improve the code.